# SQL Server disable replication

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a replicated database on my SQL server that is accessed from another SQL server. From this database, not all tables are replicated, just some ones. When I have to make changes in these tables, I have to disable the replication first, otherwise it does not allow me to make changes in these tables.

The place where I turn off the replication of these tables is the following location:

Replication > Local Publications > Properties > Articles > Tables

I would like to be able to deactivate and activate the replication of these tables from my custom program/script, using SQL statements. I have seen that when I remove tables from replication, the following columns of sys.tables change, but I don't know if anything else changes:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
where name = 'AdventureTable'

is_published = 0 or 1
is_replicated = 0 or 1
```

How should I do this properly?

Comment: May be you can check this URL:
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/altering-a-column-on-a-replicated-table

Answer (score 0):

Use the system procedure **sp_dropmergearticle**.

You need to know the sysname of the replication and the sysname of the table (Article)

```
exec sp_dropmergearticle N'MyPublishingName', N'MyTableName'
```

For more help you can see : [SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-dropmergearticle-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)